# Live video streaming using spring boot

Tags: agora.io

We are planning to implement live streaming and access to recorded lessons in telehealth application. We used android and ios for the front end and spring boot framework for back end. We want to interact with agora sdk from the backend(spring-boot). Please suggest API's to use to accomplish the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just curious, have you solved your problema? how is it now?